# ¿Por que se me reinicia los id de una tabla al borrar o vaciar?

Tags: mysql

Quisiera saber por que al borrar o vaciar una tabla los id se reinician, estoy utilizando un serial autoincremental,quisiera vaciar la tabla pero que el serial continue donde iba.

Ejemplo
si borro los registros 1,2,3 la nueva inserccion debe inicir en 4.

Comment: agrega por favor la sentencia que estas empleado al momento de eliminar los registros de tu tabla

Comment: DELETE FROM seguimiento_medico, yo se que algo sencillo pero asi deberia funcionar, antes ya funcionaba de esa forma.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente estás utilizando `TRUNCATE`, lo que ocasiona que el contador se reinicie.

En su lugar utiliza `DELETE FROM tabla`; es una operación más lenta, pero conservarás el contador.

Comment: Hola Gerry antes con delete funcionaba ,pero es que ahora no funciona ni con delete, ni con truncate,se me hace muy extraño,no se que pueda estar funcionando mal.